# how does a browser know if a javascript is from webpage or a client user has written them?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

javacript can be served to browsers that comes from server. but we can also write javascript code in the browser console.  so my question is how does a browser know that javascript is written by end user or it has come through webpage. is there some sort of ownership mechanism or stack implementation?

**can i perform xss attack from brower console. if not then why?**

i have just encountered a situation where a function was not defined inside a webpage script so throwing error. then i defined that function in browser console and then error changed to something else. (the whole code was written by me, website was mine too. but on a proper domain and is in production)

Comment: Why does it matter? A user can do whatever they want in the console, after all its their own machine. It wouldn't be considered XSS (cross-site scripting) because nothing is cross-site about it. The only thing to be worried about would be social engineering attacks where someone asks the user to paste some code into the console that they don't understand, but that has nothing to do with XSS.

Comment: @CherryDT ok. i then got xss attack wrong. but isn't it bad that user can run his code with webpage's javascript. doesn't it leave security issues? but as far as i understand, in xss attack, people could make their javascript run which browser understands , is from webpage?

Comment: I don't see the security issue here (other than social engineering, as mentioned). It's your computer, you can run on it whatever you want. The webpage's code runs on your computer, you can also run your own code on your computer, inside or outside of the webpage, it doesn't matter. And if there is a way to compromise the _server_ by running malicious code on the client then that's a vulnerability of the server, not the client...